# How to group by a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

The first one is like that:

|  | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 8 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 2020 | 9 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 1 |
| 2021 | 10 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| 2022 | 11 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 8 |
| 2023 | 12 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 8 |

The second one like that

|  | ID | ASSET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | F1 | carac3 |
| 1 | F2 | carac1 |
| 2 | F3 | carac1 |
| 3 | F4 | carac2 |
| 4 | F5 | carac2 |

I would like to get :

|  | carac1 | carac2 | carac3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | =4 (1+3) | =10 54+6 | ... |
| 2020 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023 | ... | ... | ... |

where each '...' is the sum  of F(i) for ASSET in carat(i)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use merging like below:

```
   import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'F1': [8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                    'F2': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
                    'F3': [3, 3, 4, 5, 5],
                    'F4': [4, 6, 5, 9, 9],
                    'F5': [6, 1, 1, 8, 8]},
                    index=[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5'],
                    'ASSET': ['carac3', 'carac1', 'carac1', 'carac2', 'carac2']})

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=df1.columns, right_on='ID')

grouped_df = merged_df.groupby('ASSET').sum()

transposed_df = grouped_df.T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Year'})

print(transposed_df)
```

output:

```
   ASSET Year  carac1  carac2  carac3
0       F1      19      23       8
1       F2       3       2       1
2       F3       7      10       3
3       F4      11      18       4
4       F5       2      16       6
```

Comment: It is not precisely what I need because I would like to have dates In one axis

Comment: I just edit my answer. Is this what you want ?

Comment: No. Sorry. Look at my example and you will see what I need.

Comment: After some research maybe my solution is to create a multi index column from the second df. How to be sure that they are aligned ?

Comment: i did something like that : df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2) then df1.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()...But how to be sure that the columns names coincide ?????

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use pandas to change types to dictionary. After that try dictionary comprehension:

```
dict_variable = {key:value for (key,value) in dictonary.items()}
```

I've seen someting like this, I'm new in python mb this hint will help you.

```
dict_variable = {key:value+value for (key,value) in dictonary.items()}
```

Comment: How does this even remotely address the question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this (with `df1` and `df2` your dataframes):

```py
res = pd.concat(
    [
        df1[ids].sum(axis=1).rename(col)
        for col, ids in df2.groupby("ASSET")["ID"]
    ],
    axis=1
)
```

Result for the sample:

```
      carac1  carac2  carac3
2019       4      10       8
2020       4       7       9
2021       6       6      10
2022       6      17      11
2023       6      17      12
```